# ViewControllerとGameSceneの間での数字の受け渡し

Tags: swift

いつもお世話になっております。
今回の質問は、表題の通りです。

現在野球のアプリを開発中の素人です。

詳細は下記の通りです。

投球が通過した場所をタップで指定。その場所にボールを表示(GameScene 以下 G)

タップしたゾーンがストライクかボールかを判別(G)

打者の動き（空振りとか見送り）をUISegmentedControlで指定(ViewController 以下 V)

その結果、ストライクかボールかを判別(V)

その結果をスコアボードに表示(V)

投球結果ボタンをタップ。OKなら投球を完了して、UISegmentedControlの結果をクリア。
同時に表示したボールも消える(G)

次の投球待ち(V)

という具合にしたいのですが、
そのボールを消すことができません。

この間のデータ（変数）はDelegateを使って、GからVに変数の受け渡しをしております。
ですが、投球完了ボタンをタップした時に、VからGへの受け渡しがうまくいっていないようです。
UISegConがVにあるのと、そのボタンをTabBarにStoryBoradを使っている関係で、表示したボールを消す時は、本当に一瞬だけ（ボールを消すため）だけにGに変数を渡し、すぐにGに戻ってくる必要があります。
何か分かりやすい方法はありますか？
（説明が下手ですみません）
例えば、
データの受け渡し（行ったり来たり）の際に、関数func()を使うとか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実は本当にわかりにくいので、全然ピント外れかも知れないのですが、階層構造のあるクラス間でのデータの受け渡しという話に絞らせていただきます。

通常の構成でSpriteKitのGameSceneを使用する場合、次のような階層構成になると思います。

```
ViewController(UIViewController)
  |
  +-- SKView
        |
        +-- GameScene(SKScene)
```

このような階層構造がある場合の設計の原則ですが、

- 下位の階層は、上位の階層の詳細(publicなメンバーも含めて)に一切関知しない
- 上位の階層は下位の階層の`public`な(*1)メンバー(メソッド・プロパティ)を参照して良い

とするものです。下位から上位(を含めて、階層不明のどこか)にアクセスする場合はdelegateを使うというのがApple流ですね。
(Apple製フレームワークの`ViewController - (ちょっとややこしい)View - (シンプルな)サブview`と言った構造も、概ねこの原則に従っています。)

と言うわけで、あなたの場合、下位(G)→上位(V)へは「Delegateを使って、GからVに変数の受け渡しをして」いるそうなので、この原則に従っていますから、逆向きも原則に従ってはいかがでしょうか。

具体的には、

- GameScene側に「ボールを消す」ためのメソッド(なにか値を渡す必要があればパラメータを持つようにする)を`public`(`internal`でも良いですが)に定義する
- ViewController側からはそのメソッドを呼ぶだけ

と言う形にすれば良いのではないかと思います。

*1 まだ`public`だの`private`だのは使い分けておられないかも知れませんが、「このプロパティの値をよそのクラスから自由に変えられちゃ困る」的なものは(概念的に)`private`なんだと思ってください。(そう言うのは実際に`private`にした方が良いです。)

(追記)コメントにいただいたことを踏まえてコード例を記載するとこんな感じになります。
ViewControllerでボールを消す処理を入れるメソッドの中:

```
        let scene = (self.view as! SKView).scene as! GameScene
        scene.removeBall()
```

GameSceneの中:

```
    func removeBall() {
        if let theNode = self.childNodeWithName("ball") {
            theNode.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
```

(回答中では`public`を何箇所かに書いておいて、実際には`public`を付けていませんが、Swiftの場合、`public`修飾はframework作者以外にはあまり関係ないので、とりあえず`internal`(省略時のデフォルト)にしてあります。)

元質問で「Gに変数を渡し」あたりが何のことかわからないので、何かしら足りないこともあるかも知れませんが、例によって必要に応じコメントなどでお知らせください。

Comment: 有り難いアドバイス有難うございます。
理屈は理解できました。
具体的には、・GameScene側に「ボールを消す」ためのメソッド・・・の部分ですが、どう定義すればいいですか？
現在、ボールを消すときは、
if let theNode = self.childNodeWithName("ball") {
                    theNode.removeFromParent()
                    }
とやっていますが、これを関数化　func()で囲い、Viewcontrollerから呼び出す際はどうすれば良いですか？
教えていただけますか？

Comment: `self`はGameSceneですよね。ご自身で書かれているようにfunc()で囲むだけなんですが、コメントに長いコードを書くと見にくくなるので、回答の方に追記しておきます。

Comment: アドバイス感謝します。
初回の質問の終盤で、

本当に一瞬だけ（ボールを消すため）だけにGに変数を渡し、すぐにGに戻ってくる必要があります。

と書きましたが、「すぐにVに戻ってくる必要があります。」の誤りでした。

これは、変数を使用しないとGのボールを画面から消すことができないと思い込んでいたためです。Gに関数を配置してVから呼び出すだけでボールが消せるなら変数を使う必要はありませんよね？

今回のサンプルコードをViewControllerに書くと、Value type of "GameScene" has no member "removeBall" となり、エラーになってしまいます。

まだ何かコードを追記する必要があるような気がしますが、どうしたら良いですか？

Comment: コンパイルエラーにならないところまでは確認しているので、コードの残りの部分を見ないと何とも言えないですね。まずはremoveBall()メソッドが正しくGameSceneクラスの直下のメンバーメソッドして宣言されているか(GameSceneと同じファイルだけどGameSceneの外側だとか、GameSceneのクラス内だけど別メソッドの内側とかになっていないか)を確かめてみてください。

Comment: 教わった通りremoveBall()の位置をGameScene直下に移動したところ、無事解決しました。
有難うございました。また教えて下さい。

Comment: すみません。ついでに教えていただきたいのですが、ボールを消すところまではできました。消した場所に投球数の数字を表示したいのですが、理屈は今回の件と同じと考えて良いですか？球数のIntはViewControllerで管理しています。数字を表示する場所はTouchesBigan()で取得していますが、これが、GameScene直下ではないため、インスタンス変数の使い方がわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: GameScen‌​e直下というのは、見かけ上の`GameScen‌​e`という単語の真下という意味ではないんですが、わかっておられるでしょうか。GameScene側の`touchesBegan(_:withEvent:)`メソッドは「GameSceneの直下」にないと正しく働きませんよ。「(トップレベルの)関数」、「(クラスの)メソッド」、「ネストされた関数」はみんな`func`キーワードを使って定義されますが、全部別物です。`var`や`let`で宣言される「グローバル変数」「(クラスの)インスタンス変数」「(ブロックやクロージャーなどの)ローカル変数」の違いも、コードを見て確実にこれは何とわかって使い分けておられるでしょうか。あなたのやっている(UISegmentedControlのような)UIControlベースのUIをGameSceneと連携させる、と言うのはあまり初心者が気軽に手を出すようなレベルのテクニックではありません。まずはオブジェクト指向プログラミング言語の基礎の部分をしっかり押さえて、「インスタンス変数の使い方がわかりません」と言うレベルは卒業してからかかられた方が良いですね。